# Evaluate $\int u(1+u)^{\tfrac32}du$

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to evaluate:$$\int u(1+u)^{\tfrac32}du$$

I tried to write the expression in different ways: $\int(u^{\tfrac23}+u^{\tfrac53})^{\tfrac32}du$ but it didn't help. I also wrote the expression as:

$$\int u(u+1)\sqrt{u+1}\; du\quad\quad\text{or}\quad\quad \int(u^2+u)\sqrt{u+1}\;du$$
But it didn't help too.

Comment: $v = 1 + u$ substitution may be easier.

Comment: Oh. I got it thank you.

Comment: I get $\frac27(1+u)^{\frac72}-\frac25(1+u)^{\frac52}+C$

Comment: Yes seems alright

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding and subtracting 1 in the $u$ factor gives

\begin{align}
\int u(1+u)^{\tfrac32}du&=\int (u+1)(u+1)^{3/2}\,du -\int (u+1)^{3/2}\,du\\
&=\int (u+1)^{5/2}\,du -\int (u+1)^{3/2}\,du
\end{align}

Can you continue from this?

Answer (score 1):

Integrate by parts

$$\int u(1+u)^{\tfrac32}du=\frac25\int u \>d((1+u)^{\frac52})
$$